# "Gem::InstallError: strptime requires Ruby version ~> 2.0." even after installing the requirements

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, ruby-2.0, fluentd

I was trying to install [fluentd](https://github.com/fluent/fluentd) on a ubuntu-server from source and followed the procedure given [here](http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/install-from-source).

I ran the following commands to setup the ruby environment:

```
sudo apt-get -y install ruby2.0 ruby2.0-dev
sudo apt-get -y install bundler
sudo gem2.0 install rdoc
```

Then I ran the following commands:

```
# Download the latest code from github
curl -O https://codeload.github.com/fluent/fluentd/zip/master
mv master fluentd-master.zip

unzip -o fluentd-master.zip
cd fluentd-master
bundle install
```

Running this last command `bundle install` gives the following output, culminating into error.

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake (10.4.2) 
Using cool.io (1.4.1) 
Using flexmock (1.3.3) 
Using http_parser.rb (0.6.0) 
Using json (1.8.3) 
Using msgpack (0.7.0) 
Using sigdump (0.2.3) 
Installing strptime (0.1.4) 
Gem::InstallError: strptime requires Ruby version ~> 2.0.
An error occurred while installing strptime (0.1.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install strptime -v '0.1.4'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I sym-linked `gem` to point to `gem2.0` and was able to run `gem install strptime -v '0.1.4'` successfully after that, but running `bundle install` still gives the same error.

How do I fix the problem?

Comment: Can you show us your ruby version by command `ruby -v`?

Comment: `ruby -v` gives the output `ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]` while `ruby2.0 -v` gives the output `ruby 2.0.0p384 (2014-01-12) [x86_64-linux-gnu]`.

Answer (score 0):

your current ruby version is 1.9.3, you should change it to ~> 2.0. I suggest you use [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) to install ruby. `rbenv` is a simple tool for managing multiple ruby versions.

Installation:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv
$ echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
$ echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

then install ruby:

```
rbenv install -v 2.0.0
rbenv global 2.0.0
```

check your ruby version:

```
ruby -v
```

then you can install fluentd correctly.

Comment: Did you install rbenv successfully?

Comment: To get `rbenv install` working you need to install the `ruby-build` plugin. It does not come by default. Installation instructions here: https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build